# Api takes too long to load

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have created a Web API using Microsoft web API 2.0 which interacts with DB and brings data based on that.

I have deployed the API on the staging server for testing, which takes less than 1s to respond takes about 30s to 60s to respond on the staging server.

The interesting part is when I added logs to track which part of the code is taking time on the staging server, the time span between Controller action's first line and last line was almost same for both environments i.e less than 1s around 600ms. I seriously don't know where the API is taking time to generate the response on the staging server.

Both the systems have win 10 installed and we are using IIS8 for deployment of API, Only significant change between both systems is my dev environment is having Intel i5 processor and staging is having core two duo processor but that doesn't seem an issue as there is no such load on staging server while API is running as seen on task manager, also my dev machine is 64 bit and staging is 32 bit machine.

Can anyone help that what can be the issue?

Comment: And where is the DB hosted ?

Comment: Db is hosted on both the  environments for separate APIs

Comment: Maybe this is for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160950/asp-net-web-api-2-ef6-first-call-initialization-performance

Comment: It mentions about first call but my API responses slow in each call and the code takes same time on both systems in my case.

Comment: It could be any number of different things. There's not enough here to say. You need to detail your SQL Server deployments, the networking environment(s), etc. I'd also recommend installing something like Glimpse: http://getglimpse.com/. It will show you a breakdown of where the loading time is, so you can narrow your search.